# How to autoselect CA certificate for chrome browser on MAC (Selenium)

Tags: javascript, macos, ssl-certificate, selenium-chromedriver

Currently i am automating the tests of a web application using selenium. Chrome is the browser and web app has to undergo CA certificate selection process always. There is only one certificate in the key chain and i tried few methods to select the certificate while browsing the URL, but did not work.

How can this be handled?

Answer (score 0):

If u are running it on a Ubuntu, u just have to create a file named policies.json at /etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed/

```
{
"AutoSelectCertificateForUrls": ["{\"pattern\":\"*\",\"filter\":{}}"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alvaro. will try this and let you know.

Comment: I am using MAC to automate these tests. Tried things like editing the chrome policies and few other stuff. Didnt work. Please suggest any other ways.